# AndroidAnnotations: how to access View on @ItemClick

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-annotations

I use `AndroidAnnotations` to build Android application. But I have no idea how to refactor this below to use `@ItemClick` because `@ItemClick` doesn't accept `View` parameter. By the way, I use `View` to get tag of selected `GridView`.

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
           String url = (String) view.getTag();
           intents.put("image", url);

           DetailActivity_.launch(HomeActivity.this, view.findViewById(R.id.image), intents);
       }
 });
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot add a `View` parameter, but you can use the position parameter. The problem with that there is no method to return the clicked `View`, so you have to use some logic to get the `View` from all the children.

```
@ViewById(R.id.gridViewId)
GridView gridView;

@ItemClick(R.id.gridViewId)
void itemClicked(int position) {
    int firstPosition = gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    int lastPosition = gridView.getLastVisiblePosition();

    View clickedView;

    if ((position < firstPosition) || (position > lastPosition))
        clickedView = null;

    clickedView = gridView.getChildAt(position - firstPosition);
    // do sg with clicked view
}
```

But this is actually not as clean as your code without AA... However, the `View` parameter may be supported [soon](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/1076). Until that, i suggest to stick with the old way if you really has to work with the `View` param.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is very clear. I'm waiting for AA that support `View` on `@ItemClick` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't retrieve the View with `@ItemClick` annotation, but the selected item itself.

```
@ItemClick(R.id.yourgrid_id)
void itemClicked(Object item) {

//DO SOMETHING
}
```

`item` type depends on your Grid adapter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still waiting AA that support `View`, because without `View`, I cannot send tag from selected view to another intent. :)